# Spring-Doc open api not working with Spring cloud config server @EnableConfigServer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-openui

Im using `spring boot 2.3.2.RELEASE` with `spring-cloud-config-server 2.2.4.RELEASE`. Im trying to implement the `spring-doc-openapi (1.4.3)` in a existing project. If i add `@EnableConfigServer` in one the configuration class file, the `swagger-ui.html` endpoint returns a weird json:

```
   "name":"swagger-ui",
   "profiles":[
      "index.html"
   ],
   "label":null,
   "version":null,
   "state":null,
   "propertySources":[

   ]
}
```

and not the the swagger ui as expected. Im not sure if its a bug, but would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Hello! Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its relevant to add the springdoc dependency on spring cloud config server, unless you need to explore some APIs on the config server it self.

Here is the link of a fully working example using springdoc with config server:

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos/tree/master/sample-springdoc-openapi-microservices

And this is the link of a blog which explains the natural usage with microservies and spring cloud modules:

- https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/02/20/microservices-api-documentation-with-springdoc-openapi/

Comment: I totally confirm the following example is working fine. Thanks brianbro.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @brianbro seems not to be working anymore...

Verified on: `springdoc-openapi v1.6.6` and `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server:v2.2.4.RELEASE`

Here is how I solved it:

1. List item `spring.cloud.config.server.prefix=config-server` - please note that any request to config server will require to add prefix!
2. Add following bean (sample implementation in Kotlin)

   ```
   @Bean fun configServerApi(): GroupedOpenApi =
   GroupedOpenApi.builder()
       .group("Config server")
       .pathsToMatch(
           "/config-server/**"
       )
       .build()
   ```

Now you should be able to reach swagger ui :)